# How to change Tkinter label text on button press

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I have this code, and its meant to change the text of the `Instruction` label when the item button is pressed. It doesn't for some reason, and I'm not entirely sure why. I've tried creating another button in the `press()` function with the same names and parameters except a different text.

```
import tkinter
import Theme
import Info

Tk = tkinter.Tk()
message = 'Not pressed.'

#Sets window Options
Tk.wm_title(Info.Title)
Tk.resizable(width='FALSE', height='FALSE')
Tk.wm_geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (720, 480, 0, 0))


#Method run by item button
def press():
    message = 'Button Pressed'
    Tk.update()

#item button
item = tkinter.Button(Tk, command=press).pack()

#label
Instruction = tkinter.Label(Tk, text=message, bg=Theme.GUI_hl2, font='size, 20').pack()

#Background
Tk.configure(background=Theme.GUI_bg)
Tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doing:

```
message = 'Button Pressed'
```

will not affect the label widget.  All it will do is reassign the global variable `message` to a new value.

To change the label text, you can use its [`.config()` method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) (also named `.configure()`):

```
def press():
    Instruction.config(text='Button Pressed')
```

---

In addition, you will need to call the `pack` method on a separate line when creating the label:

```
Instruction = tkinter.Label(Tk, text=message, font='size, 20')
Instruction.pack()
```

Otherwise, `Instruction` will be assigned to `None` because that is the method's return value.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: Have you seen my edit?  I added that you will also need to reposition your call to `pack` since the method returns `None`.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592730/2555451) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `message` a `StringVar` to make callback.

```
message = tkinter.StringVar()

message.set('Not pressed.')
```

You need to set `message` to be a `textvariable` for `Instruction`:

`Instruction = tkinter.Label(Tk, textvariable=message,  font='size, 20').pack()`

and then

```
def press():
    message.set('Button Pressed')
```

Comment: PY_VAR0 has replaced the "Button Not Pressed" and "Button Pressed" text it would seem

Comment: @Phoenix  don't understand your comment

Comment: When I run my program, It displays "PY_VAR0" Instead of "Button Pressed", which should be displayed after it is pressed, or "Not Pressed" before it is pressed.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'`