# Displaying text when a button is clicked in python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Here i create a 9 buttons and when button is clicked hello must be displayed on the button....i know its simple but i'm not getting where did i get wrong.Thanks in advance.
Here's the code

```
from Tkinter import *
class Design:
def __init__(self):
    self.button={}
    self.root=Tk()
    self.root.title("Simple Design")
    self.root.geometry("300x300")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            self.button[i,j]=Button(self.root,text="*",padx=12,pady=12).grid(row=i,column=j)

    self.click()



def click(self):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            handler=lambda i,j:self.update(i,j)
            print "click function"
            self.button[i,j]=Button(self.root,command=handler)

def update(self,i,j):
    self.button[i,j]=Button(self).grid()
    self.button[i,j]["text"]="Hello"
    print "Hello"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Tkinter label text on button press](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828477/how-to-change-tkinter-label-text-on-button-press)

Answer (score 0):

Right now i can't test the your code, but i see the problem here:
`self.button[i,j]=Button(self.root,text="*",padx=12,pady=12).grid(row=i,column=j)`! You are calling `.grid()`, which has no return. So your self.button[i,j] is `None`!

Just do it in 2 lines:
`self.button[i,j]=Button(self.root,text="*",padx=12,pady=12)` and `self.button[i,j].grid(row=i,column=j)`

Comment: I have changed and tried but there is no change in output.

Comment: `self.button[i,j]` isn't _empty_ per se. It will be set to `None`.

Comment: I think it's because you are doing it again in your `update`-method: `self.button[i,j]=Button(self).grid()`