# How to set a tkinter window to a constant size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm programming a little game with tkinter and briefly, I'm stuck.

I have a kind od starting menu, in which are two buttons and one label.

If I just create the frame everything is fine, it has the size 500x500 pixels

I want the background not to change when I create the buttons and the labe, but it adapts the size whatever I do. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def startgame():
    pass

mw = tk.Tk()              #Here I tried (1)
mw.title('The game')

back = tk.Frame(master=mw, width=500, height=500, bg='black')
back.pack()

go = tk.Button(master=back, text='Start Game', bg='black', fg='red',
                     command=lambda:startgame()).pack()
close = tk.Button(master=back, text='Quit', bg='black', fg='red',
                     command=lambda:quit()).pack()
info = tk.Label(master=back, text='Made by me!', bg='red',
                         fg='black').pack()

mw.mainloop()
```

I've searched around on stackoverflow and didn't get anything useful!
I've found just one question a bit similar to mine but the answer didn't work. I tried this:

(1)  mw.resizable(width=False, height=False)

I can't imagine what is the problem, I'm really desperate.

Comment: BTW, don't chain `.pack` onto the widget constructors like that!  `.pack` returns `None`, so you're assigning  `None` to `go`, `close`, and `info`. Define the widgets, _then_ pack them, like you did with `back`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592630/why-do-my-tkinter-widgets-get-stored-as-none

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You turn off `pack_propagate` by setting `pack_propagate(0)`

Turning off `pack_propagate` here basically says don't let the widgets inside the frame control it's size. So you've set it's width and height to be 500. Turning off propagate stills allows it to be this size without the widgets changing the size of the frame to fill their respective width / heights which is what would happen normally

To turn off resizing the root window, you can set `root.resizable(0, 0)`, where resizing is allowed in the `x` and `y` directions respectively.

To set a maxsize to window, as noted in the other answer you can set the `maxsize` attribute or `minsize` although you could just set the geometry of the root window and then turn off resizing. A bit more flexible imo.

Whenever you set `grid` or `pack` on a widget it will return `None`. So, if you want to be able to keep a reference to the widget object you shouldn't be setting a variabe to a widget where you're calling `grid` or `pack` on it. You should instead set the variable to be the widget `Widget(master, ....)` and then call `pack` or `grid` on the widget instead.

```
import tkinter as tk

def startgame():

    pass

mw = tk.Tk()

#If you have a large number of widgets, like it looks like you will for your
#game you can specify the attributes for all widgets simply like this.
mw.option_add("*Button.Background", "black")
mw.option_add("*Button.Foreground", "red")

mw.title('The game')
#You can set the geometry attribute to change the root windows size
mw.geometry("500x500") #You want the size of the app to be 500x500
mw.resizable(0, 0) #Don't allow resizing in the x or y direction

back = tk.Frame(master=mw,bg='black')
back.pack_propagate(0) #Don't allow the widgets inside to determine the frame's width / height
back.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1) #Expand the frame to fill the root window

#Changed variables so you don't have these set to None from .pack()
go = tk.Button(master=back, text='Start Game', command=startgame)
go.pack()
close = tk.Button(master=back, text='Quit', command=mw.destroy)
close.pack()
info = tk.Label(master=back, text='Made by me!', bg='red', fg='black')
info.pack()

mw.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want a window as a whole to have a specific size, you can just give it the size you want with the `geometry` command. That's really all you need to do.

For example:

```
mw.geometry("500x500")
```

Though, you'll also want to make sure that the widgets inside the window resize properly, so change how you add the frame to this:

```
back.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `parent_window.maxsize(x,x);` to set the maximum size. It shouldn't get larger even if you set the background, etc.

Edit: use `parent_window.minsize(x,x)` also to set it to a constant size!

Comment: I don't want it to be more little than anything but a constant size

Comment: The accepted answer to specify root.resizable(0, 0) when creating a fixed size window is not a solution for me, as it has a side effect (at least on Mac): to close/minimise the window using window control buttons the window MUST HAVE FOCUS (you have to click the window, then to click (x)). But setting root.maxsize(a, b) and root.minsize(a, b) does the thing perfectly with a single click. Thanks a lot, @SidSahay

Answer (score 4):

Here is the most simple way.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('200x200')
root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I don't think there is anything to specify.
It's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions for your problem:

1. Either you set a fixed size of the Tkinter window;                 `mw.geometry('500x500')`

OR

2. Make the Frame adjust to the size of the window automatically;`back.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)`

*The second option should be used in place of `back.pack()`

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

width = root.winfo_screenwidth() #get your Windows width size 
height = root.winfo_screenheight() #get your Windows height size 

root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))
root.resizable(False,False)

root.mainloop()

#full size Tkinter
```