# Python, 'tkinter' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to print the value `xf_in` which is entered in the GUI.

However, I get the following error message when i press the `run` button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My_Name\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/My_Name/Python Scripts/test/gui.py", line 6, in EP
    xf_In = tk.get(e_xf)
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'get'
```

I've tried to find the source of the error online but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help

My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk as imtk
from PIL import Image as im

def EP(): # Enter inputs from values typed in
      xf_In = tk.get(e_xf)
      print(xf_In)

root = tk.Tk()

l_xf = tk.Label(root, text="xA of Feed").grid(row=0)

e_xf = tk.Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1)       


run = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=EP).grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan = 2)

img = imtk.PhotoImage(im.open("x.png"))
panel = tk.Label(root, image = img).grid(row = 0, column = 2, rowspan = 7)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you think `tk.get(e_xf)` is going to do? Are you trying to get the value of the `e_xf` widget? There are many examples on this site and all over the internet for how to get the value of an entry widget, have you done any research at all?

Comment: I had tk. because i got the no .get attribute error when i had e_xf.get(). yes I am trying to get the value of the e_xf entry widget. I have done research into this but couldnt find an answer hence why i am posting here. The issue turned out to be due to the fact I was calling the grid value rather than the entry value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the `tk` module does not have a function named `get`. It might have plenty of classes whose instances have a `get` method, but you can't access them the way you're doing.

If you're trying to get the contents of the Entry, you should assign it to a name, and call `get` on that instead:

```
def EP(): # Enter inputs from values typed in
      xf_In = e_xf.get(e_xf)
      print(xf_In)

#...

e_xf = tk.Entry(root)
e_xf.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Note that this assignment is different from doing `e_xf = tk.Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1)`. If you do that, then `e_xf` will be bound to the return value of `grid`, rather than the Entry instance. `grid` returns None, so trying to call `get` on that would only give you an AttributeError. Related reading: [Why do my Tkinter widgets get stored as None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21592630/953482)

Comment: xf_In = e_xf.get(e_xf)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the grid assignment problem in my first draft. Try changing the assignment of `e_xf` as well and see if that helps.