# Python tkinter - change Label font color dynamically

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a Label that show the status of my db connection. I need to update the text of this Label whenever something happens, but also I want to change the color of this label. I'm using `update_idletasks()` method, but it just change the text not the color.

```
    self.dtbase_value = StringVar()
    self.dtbase_color = StringVar()
    self.dtbase_bg    = StringVar()

    self.dtbaselbl = Label(self.right_frame, textvariable = self.dtbase_value, fg = self.dtbase_color.get(), bg = self.dtbase_bg.get()).pack(side=TOP)
```

This is the part that I call the update.

```
    self.dtbase_value.set(self.get_current_time() + ': connection established')
    self.dtbase_color.set('SpringGreen')
    root.update_idletasks()
```

Is there any specific method to dinamically update the attributes of a Label component?

Comment: i **think** you need to remove the brackets here  `fg = self.dtbase_color.get(), bg = self.dtbase_bg.get()`

Comment: I think you want to [`trace`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) changes and call a callback function to change appearence of you Label (which is `None` right now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to get a reference to the Label object. You might be thinking "I already have one, it's `self.dtbaselbl`". But that value is actually None. You're assigning the result of `Label().pack()` to it, and `pack` always returns None. See [Why do my Tkinter widgets get stored as None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21592630/953482) for more information.

Pack and assign on separate lines:

```
self.dtbaselbl = Label(self.right_frame, textvariable = self.dtbase_value)
self.dtbaselbl.pack(side=TOP)
```

Now that you have a proper reference, you can set the label's configuration options, including color, at any time using the `.config` method.

```
self.dtbase_value.set(self.get_current_time() + ': connection established')
self.dtbaselbl.config(fg="SpringGreen")
root.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: thanks Kevin. It worked. I was trying to use `.config`, but it didn't work until i made the pack adjust.