# Why is Tkinter widget stored as None? (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object ...)(TypeError: 'NoneType' object ...)

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, attributeerror, nonetype

```
#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ... Example

try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

widget = tk.Label(root, text="Label 1").grid()
widget.config(text="Label A")

root.mainloop()
```

Above code produces the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\other\script.py", line 8, in <module>
>     widget.config(text="Label A")
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
> ```

---

Similarly the code piece:

```
#TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment Example

try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

widget = tk.Button(root, text="Quit").pack()
widget['command'] = root.destroy

root.mainloop()
```

produces the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\other\script2.py", line 8, in <module>
>     widget['command'] = root.destroy
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
> ```

---

And in both cases:

```
>>>print(widget)
None
```

Why is that, why is `widget` stored as `None`, or why do I get the errors above when I try configuring my widgets?

---

This question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592630/why-do-my-tkinter-widgets-get-stored-as-none) and is asked for a generalized answer to many related and repetitive questions on the subject. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18136131) for edit rejection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`widget` is stored as `None` because geometry manager methods [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [`place`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) return `None`, and thus they should be called on a *separate line* than the line that creates an instance of the widget as in:

```
widget = ...
widget.grid(..)
```

or:

```
widget = ...
widget.pack(..)
```

or:

```
widget = ...
widget.place(..)
```

---

And for the 2nd code snippet in the question specifically:

```
widget = tkinter.Button(...).pack(...)
```

should be separated to two lines as:

```
widget = tkinter.Button(...)
widget.pack(...)
```

---

Info: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47619078/7032856) is based on, if not for the most parts *copied* from, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21592730/7032856).