# Tkinter quit freezes

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a very simple snippet of code just to try `tkinter`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root).pack()
button = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="next",
                   command=root.quit).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The above code causes the window to freeze. Could someone explain to me what is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: It might be because the `pack()` method returns `None` which which you assigned to the `frame` variable. Change it to `frame = tk.Frame(root)` and add a line below that with `frame.pack()`.

Comment: never do `x = tk.Button(...).pack()` - Separate it into two lines.

Comment: Works as expected w/o freeze @ regular text editor + Python 3.6 + TkVersion 8.6 + Windows 7.

Comment: Somehow linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619074/why-is-tkinter-widget-stored-as-none-attributeerror-nonetype-object-ty/47619078#47619078).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seperating the `pack()` from the initialisation lines will fix your issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
frame=tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(frame,text="next",command=root.quit)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see how separating the geometry managers have anything to do with what OP is experiencing. Widgets are still created with the options that are put, just not exactly referable, and since `root` is initialized properly, `command=root.quit` option should work fine.

Comment: The proposed answer solved the issue on my side. Given your comments above stating that my code works for you, might depend on configuration

Answer (score 4):

Too late in the game, but I had this similar problem before. I was using Jupyter Notebook to run the code.

Instead of using `command=root.quit`, use `command=root.destroy`. I'm not an expert, but if I understand correctly `root.quit` attempts to quit the IDE too, whereas `root.destroy` will only exit the Tkinter window.

Comment: This is what I had to do as well. The root.quit always freezes where as root.destroy does the the trick. I am using VSCode with a .ipynb format file. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Yes this is right. I use spyder and find it is the only way I tried that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I am using Python 3.7 and Spyder. The main issue was Spyder, not the code.
I changed to Jupyter Notebook and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Making `.pack()` or `.grid()` a separate line didn't work for me. The solution was to hide the window using `root.withdraw()` before running `root.quit()` or `root.destroy()` as shown below.

```
import tkinter as tk

def quit_(root):
    root.withdraw()
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk() 
tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=lambda: quit_(root)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```