# Tkinter focus on Entry when script run

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, focus

I am using tkinter to make a small user input sort of thing.
I couldn't find how to set focus to an Entry box when the script is run.
I.e. When the window opens, the first thing that automatically gets focus is the Entry box. set_focus() or focus() doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
text = Entry(root,
        textvariable=v).grid(column=0,row=0)
text.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Tkinter widget stored as None? (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object ...)(TypeError: 'NoneType' object ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47619074/why-is-tkinter-widget-stored-as-none-attributeerror-nonetype-object-ty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geometry manager (`.grid()`, or `.pack()`, etc...) returns `None`. You must not use it on the same line as the assignment to a variable:

Your code was trying to call `.focus_set()` on a variable `text` whose value was set to `None`.

Further, the correct method to set the focus to a widget is `focus_set()`, not `set_focus()`.

```
root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
text = Entry(root, textvariable=v)
text.grid(column=0, row=0)
text. focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I ran your script, it gave me AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'set_focus' this error.

Comment: Yes, the correct method is `focus_set `, not `set_focus`. I corrected it.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing it to focus(). Thanks. It worked.