# tkinter frames not showing the widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


def message():
    text='''sfjkasjdfkjasdfjsdjfjsdlfjasd
            fjsdkfjksadjfsajdjfl    
            sdfasdjflsjdlfsldjflsjd'''
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("showing",text)


def _price_inputs():
    win2 = Tk()
    win2.title("Transactions for the project Botique")
    win2.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
    win2.configure(bg="black")


    framex = Frame(win2,width=1600,bg="RoyalBlue4",height=100,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)
    frame1 = Frame(win2,width=1000, height=400,bg="white", relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    frame2 = Frame(win2, width=775,height=100,bg="white", relief=FLAT).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    frame3 = Frame(win2,width=600,height=430,bg="gray",relief=FLAT).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)

    #framex == heading
    #frame1 == showing the infos 
    #frame2 == bottom_infos
    #frme3 == adding the buttons and widgets

    #==++++===========================title=============================

    lbl1 = Label(framex,font=("arial", 30, "bold"),bg="powder blue",fg="green",text="Hello this is the title of the page",bd=10,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)

    btn1 = Button(frame1,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="powder blue",fg="white",text="click me").pack()


    win2.mainloop()
```

I am trying to create the gui with tkinter.I am using python3.6
I made frames using tkinter and now when i try to add buttons , Labels etc it doesen't show the buttons or Labels in the output screen.

And how to i use pack for frames and grid for widgets in that frame using the pack.

Comment: Do you _not_ call the `_price_inputs` method?

Comment: You can [edit] your question post to better improve your question at anytime.

Comment: i tried but didn't work..

Comment: insted of saying the #2nd line in comment could u please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [widgets not showing in tkiner python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986021/widgets-not-showing-in-tkiner-python)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't call function in which you have defined properties. Just call function by adding `_price_inputs()` to your code at last:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


def message():
    text='''sfjkasjdfkjasdfjsdjfjsdlfjasd
            fjsdkfjksadjfsajdjfl    
            sdfasdjflsjdlfsldjflsjd'''
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("showing",text)


def _price_inputs():
    win2 = Tk()
    win2.title("Transactions for the project Botique")
    win2.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
    win2.configure(bg="black")


    framex = Frame(win2,width=1600,bg="RoyalBlue4",height=100,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)
    frame1 = Frame(win2,width=1000, height=400,bg="white", relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    frame2 = Frame(win2, width=775,height=100,bg="white", relief=FLAT).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    frame3 = Frame(win2,width=600,height=430,bg="gray",relief=FLAT).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)

    #framex == heading
    #frame1 == showing the infos 
    #frame2 == bottom_infos
    #frme3 == adding the buttons and widgets

    #==++++===========================title=============================

    lbl1 = Label(framex,font=("arial", 30, "bold"),bg="powder blue",fg="green",text="Hello this is the title of the page",bd=10,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)

    btn1 = Button(frame1,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="powder blue",fg="white",text="click me").pack()


    win2.mainloop()
_price_inputs()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't see new items, `lbl1` and `btn1` as they're:

1. Children to `win2`, not any frames
2. Blocked by another frame, `frame3`

---

## 1

`lbl1` and `btn1` are children to `win2`, because passing None as the first positional argument or by default, the widget's parent is assigned as the Tk instance.

`lbl1` and `btn1` are instantiated with parent arguments as `None`, because:

```
framex = Frame(win2,width=1600,bg="RoyalBlue4",height=100,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)
...
frame1 = Frame(win2,width=600,height=430,bg="red",relief=FLAT).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
```

lines are *identical* to that of:

```
Frame(win2,width=1600,bg="RoyalBlue4",height=100,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)
framex = None
...
Frame(win2,width=600,height=430,bg="red",relief=FLAT).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
frame1 = None
```

Because both `framex` and `frame3` [are the return of the method `pack` which is *always* `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47619074/7032856).

One could fix this by separating the geometry manager line with the widget instantiation line:

```
framex = Frame(win2,width=1600,bg="RoyalBlue4",height=100,relief=GROOVE)
framex.pack(side=TOP)
...
frame1 = Frame(win2,width=600,height=430,bg="red",relief=FLAT)
frame1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
```

---

## 2

Comment out frame3 line to see that `lbl1` and `btn1` actually exists:

```
#frame3 = Frame(win2,width=600,height=430,bg="red",relief=FLAT).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox


"""def message():
    text='''sfjkasjdfkjasdfjsdjfjsdlfjasd
            fjsdkfjksadjfsajdjfl    
            sdfasdjflsjdlfsldjflsjd'''
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("showing",text)"""


def _price_inputs():
    win2 = Tk()
    win2.title("Transactions for the project Botique")
    win2.geometry("1600x800+0+0")
    win2.configure(bg="white")


    framex = Frame(win2,width=1600,bg="RoyalBlue4",height=100,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)
    #frame1 = Frame(win2,width=1000, height=400,bg="white", relief=SUNKEN).pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    frame2 = Frame(win2, width=775,height=100,bg="black", relief=FLAT).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    frame3 = Frame(win2,width=800,height=450,bg="gray",relief=FLAT).pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)

    #framex == heading
    #frame1 == showing the infos 
    #frame2 == bottom_infos
    #frme3 == adding the buttons and widgets

    #==++++===========================title=============================

    lbl1 = Label(framex,font=("arial", 30, "bold"),bg="black",fg="green",text="Hello this is the title of the page",bd=10,relief=GROOVE).pack(side=TOP)

    btn1 = Button(frame3,font=("arial",15,"bold"),bd=8,bg="black",fg="white",text="before 60 hrs",relief=GROOVE).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    btn2 = Button(frame3,font=("arial",15,"bold"),bd=8,bg="black",fg="white",text="full_stock",relief=GROOVE).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    btn3 = Button(frame3,font=("arial",15,"bold"),bd=8,bg="black",fg="white",text="delivery_report",relief=GROOVE).pack(side=BOTTOM)

    before = IntVar()
    stock_full = IntVar()
    delivery_report = IntVar()

    btn4 = Button(win2,font=("arial",15,"bold"),bd=8,bg="black",fg="white",text="hello",relief=GROOVE).pack(side=BOTTOM)

    '''import Tkinter as tk
import ImageTk

FILENAME = 'image.png'
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
canvas.pack()
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = FILENAME)
canvas.create_image(125, 125, image=tk_img)
quit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Quit", command = root.quit, anchor = 'w',
                    width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5")
quit_button_window = canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor='nw', window=quit_button)    
root.mainloop()
'''
    win2.mainloop()
```

Comment: This fixed the problems

Comment: Code without an explanation isn't very helpful to others. Could you please describe what you did to fix the problem?