# Compare tkinter Entry to actual addition answer

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to compare the input of an Entry box to the actual answer. This is one of my first python projects and I'm still very confused and to be honest I don't even know how to start asking the question.

The user will click either the addition or subtraction button. A string will appear asking "What does 4 + 5 equal?" The numbers are generated randomly.

I then insert an Entry box using the tkinter library. **I don't know how to `get()` the input and compare it to the sum or difference of the actual numbers.**

I was trying to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hst3AWjxF5o&t=136s) but I've failed using other methods as well. FYI, I was focusing on the addition method mostly so if you test, that with addition first.

```
from tkinter import Entry
import tkinter as tk
import random as rand

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("450x450+500+300")
root.title("Let's play Math!")

welcomeLabel = tk.Label(text="LET'S PLAY MATH!").pack()
startLabel = tk.Label(text='Select a math operation to start').pack()

def addition():
    a = rand.randrange(1,10,1)
    b = rand.randrange(1,10,1)
    global Answer
    Answer = a + b

    tk.Label(text="What does " + str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " equal? ").place(x=0, y=125)
    global myAnswer
    myAnswer = Entry().place(x=300, y= 125)

def checkAnswer():
    entry = myAnswer.get()

    while int(entry) != Answer:
        if int(entry) != Answer:
            tk.Label(text="Let's try again.").pack()
        elif int(entry) == Answer:
            tk.Label(text="Hooray!").pack()


addBtn = tk.Button(text="Addition", command=addition).place(x=100, y = 60)
subBtn = tk.Button(text="Subtraction", command=subtraction).place(x=200, y=60)
checkBtn = tk.Button(text="Check Answer", command=checkAnswer).place(x=300, y = 150)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should narrow down your code to the actual question you're asking. Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with the code. But I think you're generally on the right track, except what's the purpose of `while myAnswer != Answer:`? The label you've created _will_ be shown after the very first time an answer is wrong anyway, so no need for a while loop there, rather there are other problems.

Comment: Ok, I've eliminated the part where I'm subtracting as I'd not yet done much work on it. If I take out anything else, it will be difficult to understand what I'm referencing.

Comment: No, you can take out much more else, in fact you _should_. Otherwise this the question for: _"How can I create A GUI for a Math Quiz?"_. Which is too-broad as far as stackoverflow is concerned and will probably be closed.

Comment: `myAnswer` is a local variable defined in the `addition()` function, so you can't reference it in the `checkAnswer()` function since it doesn't exist there. You could make it a `global` variable to get around this.

Comment: @martineau Ok, let me add those on there. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to fix your issue is separate the creation of your `Entry()` object from the placing of it:

```
def addition():
    a = rand.randrange(1,10,1)
    b = rand.randrange(1,10,1)
    global Answer
    Answer = int(a + b)

    tk.Label(text="What does " + str(a) + " + " + str(b) + " equal? ").place(x=0, y=125)
    global myAnswer
    myAnswer = Entry()
    myAnswer.place(x=300, y= 125)
```

`Entry()` returns the entry object, which has a `get()` method. However, when you chain `.place()`, you return its result instead, which is `None`. Therefore you never actually store the `Entry` object in your variable.

Also, it is a good idea to ensure that `Answer` is an `int` as well.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. That worked. Thank you so much! I'll update the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the answer do `answer = myanswer.get()` or any other variable name. To compare it to the correct answer do

```
if int(answer) == correctAnswer:
   #the code
```

is that what you were asking?

Comment: That's one of the mistakes in the code. The part with `intAnswer`, which can be defined as `intAnswer = int(myAnswer.get())` in one of the many solutions. Except the code rather tries to compare an entry widget to an Integer.

Comment: @Nae I was not trying to do int(Answer). According to the video on the original answer, I had to create yet another variable and i didn't know what to call it.

Comment: so you made this question asking what to call your variable?

Comment: @Nahuatl_19650 Be that as it may, the `Answer = a + b` returns an `int` and `myAnswer.get()` returns a `str`. If you want to compare them you need to convert one or the other in the most simplistic of the solutions.

Comment: That is why I had that there Nahuatl_19650

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the input, and compare to the sum of the two variables.

Comment: It says how to get the input in my answer

Comment: @Nahuatl_19650 Did this tell you what you needed to know? If not **please specify** in the question and please tell me you did so.

Comment: if it did tell you what you needed, press the little check button next to the star

Comment: @Hippolippo I tried using your method and I'm still not getting the expected "try again" or "hooray" message. I'll update the code above.

Comment: @Nahuatl_19650 the get function works, the reason you are not getting your message is because your check answer command isn't hooked up. That is a derpy thing to do :)

Comment: You're right, let me add the command. However, Now I get a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: take out that textvar thing.

Comment: Nothing yet. It's given the error on answer = Answer.get(). Now updated to entry = myAnswer.get() - 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: maybe use `.grid()` or `.pack()` instead or `.place()` It normally works for me and I don't really use `.place()`

Comment: @Hippolippo Changing the layout manager has nothing to do with that error. It is simply because `myAnswer` is not an `Entry` object. It is the  `return`ed object of method `place` used on `myanswer` object, which is `None`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21592630/7032856.

Comment: @Nae I realized that mid-reading your comment, I have no idea why I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349453/compare-tkinter-entry-to-actual-addition-answer#comment83685773_48349453) and below is an example that responds to whether or not the number entered to `answer` is `"Correct!"` or `"False!"` when the user clicks on `answer_btn`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as rand

def is_correct():
    global answer, check
    if answer.get() == str(a + b):
        check['text'] = "Correct!"
    else:
        check['text'] = "False!"

def restart():
    global question, check
    random_nums()
    question['text'] = "{}+{}".format(a, b)
    check['text'] = "Please answer the question!"

def random_nums():
    global a, b
    a = rand.randrange(1, 10, 1)
    b = rand.randrange(1, 10, 1)

root = tk.Tk()

#create widgets
question = tk.Label(root)
answer = tk.Entry(root, width=3, justify='center')
check = tk.Label(root)
tk.Button(root, text="Check", command=is_correct).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="New question", command=restart).pack()

#layout widgets
question.pack()
answer.pack()
check.pack()

restart()
root.mainloop()
```