# Buttons and fields go off screen, when using Frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to make a basic GUI with 3 rows.

This is how it looks like now:
[Picture Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoTto.png)

Actually this was how I imagined it, but I have no idea why the buttons and inputs goes off the maximum window size.

The code:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Tidal Bot")
window.geometry("960x540")
#window.resizable(False, False)
#canvas = tkinter.Canvas(borderwidth=0, width=960, height=540)

top_frame = tkinter.Frame(window, bg="gray", width=960, height=30).grid(row=1)
input1 = tkinter.Entry(top_frame).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0)
input2 = tkinter.Entry(top_frame).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
tkinter.Button(top_frame, text="Add User").grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)


mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(window, bg="black", width=960, height=30).grid(row=2)
tkinter.Button(mid_frame, text="Remove User").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0)
tkinter.Button(mid_frame, text="Start Song").grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10)
tkinter.Button(mid_frame, text="Stop Song").grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10)

bottom_frame=tkinter.Frame(window, bg="blue", width=960, height=480).grid(row=3)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `top_frame`, `mid_frame`, and `bottom_frame` are `None`, as are `input1` and `input2` Are you aware of that? [Why do my Tkinter widgets get stored as None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592630/why-do-my-tkinter-widgets-get-stored-as-none)

Comment: what do you mean? Why are they?

Comment: The answer to the question "why are they" can be found by following the link I provided in the comment.